# WebGL texture turns black in Safari on OSX

Tags: html, macos, safari, webgl

I am having an issue in Safari on OSX with WebGL enabled.  I can load an image into a texture, however, whenever I attempt to redraw after some operation the texture turns black.  This issue does not occur in Chrome or Firefox.  I have tested on Safari 5.1.9 and 6.0.4.  Here is a fiddle showing the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/LTz37/1/

The texture will load properly but after pressing the 'Left' or 'Right' button it will turn black.

Snippet causing the problem:

```
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([x1, y1, x2, y1, x1, y2, x1, y2, x2, y1, x2, y2]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug in Safari (6.0.4)

Here's the test https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/state/state-uneffected-after-compositing.html

If you just want a solution, rebind the texture. Otherwise ignore Safari until they officially release WebGL. Safari fails tons of conformance tests and is not ready to run WebGL with out lots of subtle issues. At least as of Safari version 6.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The texture needs to bound before each draw operation.  Below is the updated draw(...) function:

```
function draw(gl, image, x, y) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    setRectangle(gl, x, y, image.width, image.height);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

I updated the fiddle with the updated code commented out.

Comment: That's a bug in Safari. If the user has not unbound the texture the browser should not be unbinding it. There's a reason WebGL is hidden under two layers of menus in Safari. Because it's not done.

Comment: Here's the test: FF and Chrome pass, Safari (6.0.4) fails. https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/state/state-uneffected-after-compositing.html